# Passing a boot menu option to GRUB on a Live USB drive?

Tags: grub, uefi, clonezilla

I have an ubuntu system, and I want to have a semi-automated way of running a clonezilla unattended image / re-image from a USB drive.
To that end, I've modified the GRUB menu items to be along these lines: (One for Restore, one for image):

```
menuentry "RESTORE IMAGE" --id live-default {   $linux_cmd /live/vmlinuz boot=live union=overlay username=user config components noswap edd=on nomodeset enforcing=0 noprompt ocs_prerun="mount -L Images /mnt" ocs_prerun1="mount --bind /mnt/images /home/partimag/" ocs_live_run="ocs-sr -g auto -e1 auto -e2 -r -j2 -c -k0 -scr -icds -p reboot restoredisk ask_user ask_user" keyboard-layouts=en-us ocs_live_batch="yes" locales=en_US.UTF-8 vga=788 ip= nosplash net.ifnames=0 i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1   $initrd_cmd /live/initrd.img }
```

What I want to be able to do from the running machine is something like the following:

1. Set next boot (using efibootmgr?) to USB drive
2. touch or set *something* to choose either the RESTORE or IMAGE option on the USB drive GRUB menu item.
3. Reboot into USB drive, run the selected boot path

The dumb way I can think of this is modifying the USB grub.conf each time to set the default menu item. There has to be a better way, right?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Use efibootmgr you mentioned

Step 2: There is a `set default="0"` in /clonezilla-usb-drive/boot/grub.cfg

Replace it with your menuentry title or id or index

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#default